# Опечатка в советах по расширенному поиску

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[На странице поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search) справа от поля ввода стоит ссылка `Советы по расширенному поиску`. Она открывает колонку подсказок по параметрам поиска:

[image: Советы по расширенному поиску]

UPD из комментариев:

1. вместо `"слов здесь"` лучше `"слова в кавычках"`
2. вместо `ответа` нужно `ответы`
3. вместо `title:apples` давайте сделаем `title:яблоки`

Comment: А что такое "слов здесь"? Наверное, это было `exact "words here"`

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, [так и есть](http://stackoverflow.com/search). Можно перевести как `точно: "слова в кавычках"`.

Comment: Хороший вариант, если нашли в транзифексе - поправьте пожалуйста и киньте сюда ссылку, я зайду и нажму Review. )

Comment: И "ответа" тоже сразу можно, очевидно же.

Comment: И `title:яблоки` )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нашёл в Транзифексе [words here](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265644?q=words%20here), но не понимаю, добавлять ли кавычки в перевод. Их не видно, но, возможно, Транзифекс их не показывает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Для `answers / ответа` есть [две записи](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40261567?qt=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0&q=answers): `5762` и `5973`. Добавил своё вариант к обоям, предполагая, что так их будет легче найти и что ненужный вариант можно забраковать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Похоже, для `title: apples` [перевода нет](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265627?q=apples).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44411/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-gleb-kemarsky).

Comment: (via google translate): 
Я сделал изменения , чтобы позволить "apples" для перевода ; что следует развернуть в ближайшее время

Comment: Добавил переводы, обновил строки. Сейчас строка «ответы» имеет не верную форму (ошибка была не в переводе, а в коде). Правильная форма должна подцепиться автоматически.