# Описание блока "исключить" в советах по расширенному поиску

Tags: предложение, локализация, нет-в-transifex, поиск

В советах по расширенному поиску надо подправить содержимое блока "исключить". Сейчас он выглядит так:

[image: tag-apples]

Связанный [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3567/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83) по расширенному поиску.

Answer (score 1):

Хотелось бы видеть так:

> -[метка] 
>   -яблоки

По аналогии с уже имеющимися вариантами из блоков "метки" и "разделы".